# How to create two rows with three columns using mustache.js as a logic-less template system?

Tags: html, css, mustache

I'm using mustache.js as my template system, I'm not very experienced with logic-less
templates so I decided to ask you this question.

I have the following html structure, two rows with 3 columns each, like so:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="column-third">
      <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column-third">
      <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column-third">
      <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="column-third">
      <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column-third">
      <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column-third">
      <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

What I have at the moment on my template is the following

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-row">
    {{#contentListToRender}}
      <div class="column-third">
        <p><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></p>
      </div>
    {{/contentListToRender}}
  </div>
</div>
```

But as you can already guess that will fill the row with as many elements (columns) 
I have in contentListToRender.

I was wondering if there's a way of doing this and still keep the html structure,
or I should start thinking of chaning the html structure and use CSS to style the appearance?

Thank you for your help,
David

Edit, followed pawel comment.

I assume you mentioned to do something like this?

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    {{#contentListToRender}}
      {{#rows}}
        <div class="grid-row">
          {{#columns}}
            <div class="column-third">
              <p><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></p>
            </div>
          {{/columns}}
        </div>
      {{/rows}}
    {{/contentListToRender}}
</div>
```

Being my `contentListToRender` composed this way:

```
var contentListToRender = function() {
  return {rows: [ { columns: [column, column, column] }, {columns: [column, column, column]} ]}
}
```

Would that be an acceptable way of accomplish this?

Comment: You can transfrom the `contentListToRender` list into groups of up to 3 items (rows) before passing to the template, then iterate over the groups and render a row for each group with loop rendering the items inside.

Comment: Hi @pawel, I've edited my question to clarify your explanation, would it be that the way you would imagine to solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: yeah, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: That works, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the solution I build for this, in case someone ends up in the same place as me.

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    {{#contentListToRender}}
    {{#rows}}
        <div class="grid-row">
        {{#columns}}
            <div class="column-third">
            <p><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></p>
            </div>
        {{/columns}}
        </div>
    {{/rows}}
    {{/contentListToRender}}
</div>
```

**And the function to split the elements into rows and columns**

```
var contentListToRender = function(elements) {
var rows    = { rows: [] };
var columns = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var base_path = elements[i].base_path;
    var title     = elements[i].title;

    var column = {base_path: base_path, title: title};

    if ((columns.length > 0) && (columns.length % 3 == 0)) {
    // when the columns array has reached 3 elements
    // then add those columns to the rows
    rows.rows.push({columns: columns});

    // Then clear the columns array
    // and push the current column to the columns array
    columns = [];
    columns.push(column);
    } else {
    columns.push(column);
    }
}

// push the last columns to the last row
rows.rows.push({columns: columns});

return rows;
}
```

Comment: Best way to do it

Comment: Hello, I know it's been a long time. I did this using bootstrap+mustache but I would like to see how you implemented this contentListToRender function to make it render a 2x3 grid using mustache. I have shared my bootstrap/mustache approach  
https://jsfiddle.net/webdesignmx05/96bgtq7j/26/
Would you be able to share a working JS fiddle of this solution? I'm not sure how to make that function work with the Mustache render.  Thanks.